# Docker Windows: opening a Path starting at C: (docker: Error response from daemon: mkdir C:: permission denied.)

Tags: docker

I use Docker on my Windows system and run following commands in the Windows Subsystem for Linux:

```
docker run --name selenium-container -d -p 4444:4444 -p 5900:5900 -v C:/Users/Alexa/OneDrive/Backend-web-architecture/github-repos/data-privacy-api:/dev/shm selenium/standalone-chrome-debug
```

This yields:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: mkdir C:: permission denied.
```

Since I was in the `data-privacy-api` folder, I also tried:

```
docker run --name selenium-container -d -p 4444:4444 -p 5900:5900 -v "$(pwd):/dev/shm selenium/standalone-chrome-debug"
```

However, this lead to following error:

```
"docker run" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker run --help'.

Usage:  docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]

Run a command in a new container
```